# method setAuthorIdAttribute is not called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `Post` model with a `setAuthorIdAttribute` method used for setting the post author id with the id of the logged user.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'subtitle', 'slug', 'content', 'draft', 'author_id', 'category_id'];

    /**
     * An post belongs to an author
     */
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    // Some code here...

    /**
     * Add the author of the post
     */
    public function setAuthorIdAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->attributes['author_id'] = Auth::id();
    }
}
```

I create my `Post` with this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = Post::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('posts.show', ["post" => $post]);
}
```

When I put a `dd()` inside the `setAuthorIdAttribute` nothing happen. Why ?

Comment: Catch-22... that method triggers when a new author_id is set, but you're probably not setting an author_id from the request, right? So it'll never trigger unless you set it manually, in which case it's redundant.

Comment: Oh okay, you're right. Is there a way for setting an attribute inside a model when created ? Or I have to do it in my controller?

Comment: Sounds like you want to hook into the creating or created event - here's some info on that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events

Although that said, if they're relations I typically prefer not to set the foreign keys like that, instead choosing to use the actual relations in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the attribute value in model using models boot method something like:

```
public function boot()
{
    Model::creating(function ($model)
        return $model->attributes['author_id'] = Auth::id();

    });
    Model::updating(function ($model)
        return $model->attributes['author_id'] = Auth::id();
    });
}
```

This will fill `author_id` attribute with `Auth::id()` on each create and update event of this model.

Comment: You can use `saving` instead, it catches both `creating` and `updating`.

Comment: That's perfect! (I only need creating but thanks for the tip)